# Use str.contains then fuzzy match remaining elements

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, match

I have a data frame which contains a column of strings and a master list which I need to match them to. I want this match to be added as a separate column to the data frame. Since the data frame is about 1 million rows I want to first do "string contains" and if it does not contain a string from the master list I want to fuzzy match them at a threshold of 85, then if there is still no match, just return the value in the data frame column.

```
m_list = [FOO,BAR,DOG]

df

 Name        Number_Purchased  

ALL FOO            1
ALL FOO            4
BARKY              2
L.T. D.OG          1
PUMPKINS           3
```

I'm trying to achieve this outcome:

```
df2

 Name        Number_Purchased   Match_Name    Match_Score

ALL FOO            1               FOO           100
ALL FOO            4               FOO           100
BARKY              2               BAR           95
L.T. D.OG          1               DOG           90
PUMPKINS           3               PUMKINS       25
```

My code looks like this:

```
def matches(df, m_list):
    if df['Name'].contains('|'.join(m_list)):
        return m_list, 100
    else:
    new_name, score = process.extractOne(df.name, m_list, scorer = fuzz.token_set_ratio)    
        if score > 85:
            return new_name, score
        else:
            return name, score

df['Match_Name'], df['Match_Score'] = zip(*df.apply(matches))
```

I've edited it several times and keep having errors either "str" does not contain attribute "str" or  there is a difference in shape of arrays causing problems. How can I adjust this code so it's functional but also scale-able  for a column with 1 million+ rows?

Comment: What if I have `DOLOLOL G`. Will this still match `DOG`?

Comment: does `process.extract` only accept 1 string at a time?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I wouldn't think so. The way I understand fuzzy string matching it should be degree of edits away from what you are looking for so    L.T. D.OG would be closer than DOLOLOL G.

Comment: @djk47463 I am actually unsure. I didn't think so since i've  seen it used on some large examples but I could be mistaken.